# AsynkTask arguments confusion

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the following fully working code which was cobbled together with a bit of cut & paste from other people's examples:

```
private class Get_tweets_async_task_class extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        array_of_single_tweets = getTweets(params[0], 1);

        return null;
    } 

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params)
    {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img)
    {
        update_display_list();
    }

    protected void onCancelled()
    {
    }
}
```

My code does not in fact need anything to do with bitmaps (that was a hangover from the example) and now I'm trying to get rid of it. I edited the code as follows:

```
private class Get_tweets_async_task_class extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        array_of_single_tweets = getTweets(params[0], 1);

        return null;
    } 

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... params)
    {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute()
    {
        update_display_list();
    }

    protected void onCancelled()
    {
    }
}
```

but now the code no longer works. Did I do something wrong in my removal of the bitmap?

**Edit:** Sorry I mistyped the onPostExecute line - now corrected

Comment: 1/ use @override over each method you override. this way you'll know more about the errors you are facing. 2/ Void is a special class in android used to represent a void. Your onPostExecute must take a Void parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing)

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your `onPostExecute` method.
It still receiving `Bitmap` as a result, change it to Void.

You edit your post but the problem is the same in `onPostExecute`.
Please check the official documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html